# Disable scrollbar on new frame

Tags: frames, scroll-bars

I would like to make sure that scrollbars never show up on my windows, but I recently noticed that when I created a new frame with `C-x 5 2` the new frame gets a scrollbar, even though the original frame does not. The lines that might be relevant from my `init.el` are below:

```el
(scroll-bar-mode -1)
(if (fboundp 'scroll-bar-mode) (scroll-bar-mode -1))
(if (fboundp 'tool-bar-mode) (tool-bar-mode -1))
(if (fboundp 'menu-bar-mode) (menu-bar-mode -1))
```

I can still use `M-x toggle-scroll-bar` to turn it off in the new frame, but I feel like that shouldn't be necessary.

To clarify, I'm using `emacsclient -c &` to start Emacs on Ubuntu, and when I do this I get a scroll bar.  `C-h v scroll-bar-mode` gives me:

```
scroll-bar-mode is a variable defined in `scroll-bar.el'.
Its value is nil
Original value was right

Documentation:
Specify whether to have vertical scroll bars, and on which side.
Possible values are nil (no scroll bars), `left' (scroll bars on left)
and `right' (scroll bars on right).
To set this variable in a Lisp program, use `set-scroll-bar-mode'
to make it take real effect.
Setting the variable with a customization buffer also takes effect.

You can customize this variable.
```

So the value of `scroll-bar-mode` is properly set to `nil`, but somehow Emacs is ignoring this to give me a scroll bar anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also ran into this issue, until I added the following code.  (I believe I came across the snippet here on Stack Exchange, but sorry I don't recall the author.)

```el
(defun my/disable-scroll-bars (frame)
  (modify-frame-parameters frame
                           '((vertical-scroll-bars . nil)
                             (horizontal-scroll-bars . nil))))
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'my/disable-scroll-bars)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can adjust the [frame parameters](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/elisp-manual-21-2.8/html_node/elisp_451.html) in the `default-frame-alist` to tell Emacs you never want scroll bars.  Add the following to your init file:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist
             '(vertical-scroll-bars . nil))
```

Comment: I feel like that should work, but it doesn't. Still get the scroll bar, but only on the second frame.

Comment: @Ryan: strange!  The above works for me.  The only other thing in my init file that might be relevant is an old `(toggle-scroll-bar -1)` that I hadn't removed.  You could try adding that as well, but beyond that, I'm out of guesses.

Comment: Okay, so it actually works on Ubuntu, but not on Windows. Next time I'm on the Windows side I'll check `(toggle-scroll-bar)`.

Comment: Now I don't even know what to think. Rebooted, and now it's not working in Ubuntu, either. Every new frame is created with the scroll bar, and I have to `M-x toggle-scroll-bar` to get rid of it.

Comment: Yes, MS Windows is particular in this. Other than that, I'd recommend *customizing option* `default-frame-alist`. There's a reason it's a user option.

Answer (score 3):

Not everyone wants to use customize, but using it to disable scrollbars makes the issue disapear. The variables you want are: `scroll-bar-mode` and `horizontal-scroll-bar-mode`.

If not using a customize file, customize can still be utilized by putting these in your init:

```el
;; disable scrollbars
(customize-set-variable 'scroll-bar-mode nil)
(customize-set-variable 'horizontal-scroll-bar-mode nil)
```

That will suffice to disable any and all scrollbars in any frame type.